# Selecting multiple hit-scoped custom dimensions with bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to get a list of customers who made at least one purchase on a given day. The bigquery below works when just selecting date and customer_id. However, city always returns null, though I know the data exists.

Do I need to use a different approach when selecting multiple hit-scoped custom dimensions?

```
SELECT date
,CASE WHEN hits.customdimensions.index = 5 
 THEN hits.customdimensions.value END as customer_id
,CASE WHEN hits.customdimensions.index = 50 
 THEN hits.customdimensions.value END as city
FROM (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([16475821.ga_sessions_],
      TIMESTAMP('2016-09-01'), TIMESTAMP('2016-09-07'))
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
HAVING sum(case when hits.eventInfo.eventAction = 'purchase' then 1 end) > 0 
       and customer_id is not null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't have any data to test again, but visually assessing - below should work for you

```
SELECT 
  date,
  MAX(CASE WHEN hits.customdimensions.index = 5 
           THEN hits.customdimensions.value END) WITHIN RECORD AS customer_id
  MAX(CASE WHEN hits.customdimensions.index = 50 
           THEN hits.customdimensions.value END) WITHIN RECORD AS city
  SUM(CASE WHEN hits.eventInfo.eventAction = 'purchase' 
           THEN 1 END) WITHIN RECORD AS purchases_count
FROM (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([16475821.ga_sessions_],
      TIMESTAMP('2016-09-01'), TIMESTAMP('2016-09-07')))
HAVING purchases_count > 0
AND NOT customer_id IS NULL
```

Comment: Works! What's the rational behind record-scoping the aggregations?

Comment: This is a way to extract needed nested items from each record(row). By using max() you effectively "extracting" only what you need and ignoring rest. And by using sum() you counting purchases inside record. That is how I saw you data and respectively wrote query